# Ubuntu 16.04 freezes frequently on Lenovo Thinkpad

Tags: 16.04, grub2, lenovo, freeze

I recently purchased a Lenovo Thinkpad E470 which came with Windows 10. I removed this and installed the latest Ubuntu (17.10), however removed this and changed to Ubuntu 16.04.3 after hearing about some issues with 17.10

Ubuntu 16.04 has worked great except that it freezes, seemingly randomly, but very often. (This also happened on 17.10) When this freeze happens the only solution manually powering off with the power button. Sometimes it freezes immediately after login, before opening any software, other times after 10 minutes, to an hour or so. There is no warning when it happens, and isn't triggered by particular software.

I have tried these fixes:

1. Updated to latest BIOS from Lenovo
2. Updated kernel to Linux 4.14.0-041400-generic from 4.10.42 which was default
3. Entered the grub file and changed the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT to contain intel_idle.max_cstate=1, did sudo update-grub and rebooted. This didn't help and made no noticeable difference.

Please, if anyone can help, it'd be much appreciated, the laptop is unusable like this!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a Lenovo 510 14AST with an AMD chipset. After a lot of testing I found out that the AMD Radeon graphics model R5 is too new to be supported by the mesa open source VGA driver.

So I did a fresh install of Xubuntu (which behaved most stable due to a simpler GUI) and then immediately installed the AMDGPU-PRO driver as described here http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx